# Prove that $P(A\cup B) = P (B) + P (A)\cdot P (B^c)$

Tags: probability

Suppose A and B are independent events. Show that $P(A\cup B) = P (B) + P (A)\cdot P (B^c)$

Could someone tell me how i can prove this?

Remembering that two events are independent if $P (A \cap B) = P (A)\cdot  P (B)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Before asking for help, it is advisable to show us what are your attempts at solving the proposed problem.

Comment: HINT: first show that if $A$ and $B$ are independent then $A$ and $B^\complement$ are also independent

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the formula $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. 
You have also provided $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$ since $A$ and $B$ are independent. 
You can use them to express the terms in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{split}P(A\cup B)&=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)\\
&=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)\text{ independence}\\
&=P(B)+P(A)(1-P(B)) \text{ factorization}\\
&=P(B)+P(A)P(B^c) \text{ definition of complement}\end{split}$$